# Deprecate REST API using java/selenium

Tags: java, rest, user-interface

I'm new to this site but i hope i'll get some responses. 
I'm using java/selenium web driver and trying to resolve an issue i came across during the posting of an API through url.

The command im trying to send through url (and make PatientID as a parameter/variable) is :

```
$ curl http://localhost:8040/modalities/Test101/find-study -X POST -d '{"PatientID":"0555643F"}'
```

My intended Java/selenium code to resolve this as follows:

```
 RestAssured.baseURI = "http://evdcvrtmbuild01:8040/modalities/Test101/find-study/{"PatientID ": "0555643F"};
   RequestSpecification httpRequest = RestAssured.given();
        Response responseA = httpRequest.post("");
          String  body = responseA.getBody().asString();    
          System.out.println("BODY:" + body);
```

Currently, i'm not getting a response as i think i'm not getting the url syntax wright.

Any suggestions ?.

Thanks, 
A.M.

Answer (score 0):

The patientID should be in the body (if you do a POST), not in the url!

Try something like this:

```
RestAssured.baseURI = "http://evdcvrtmbuild01:8040/modalities/Test101/find-study/";
RequestSpecification httpRequest = RestAssured.given();
httpRequest.body("{\"PatientID \": \"0555643F\"}"); 
Response responseA = httpRequest.post("");
String  body = responseA.getBody().asString();    
System.out.println("BODY:" + body);
```

Comment: I tried the above but got:

 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid number of path parameters. Expected 1, was 0. Undefined path parameters are: "PatientID ": "0555643F".
 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
 at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source

Comment: Hi Tom, after a retest, i got the following error:                                                          log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.http.impl.conn.BasicClientConnectionManager).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
BODY:{
   "HttpError" : "Internal Server Error",
   "HttpStatus" : 500,
   "Message" : "Unknown DICOM tag",
   "Method" : "POST",
   "OrthancError" : "Unknown DICOM tag",
   "OrthancStatus" : 27,
   "Uri" : "/modalities/Test101/find-study/"
}